# перевод документов в pdf с помощью libreoffice

Tags: python, linux, pdf, open-office, libre-office

На данный момент перевожу документы в pdf через libreoffice, вызовом soffice. 
Можно ли как то повысить производительность ? На данный момент я так понимаю он обрабатывает их последовательно, и это занимает достаточно много времени. Может можно как то понизить качество перевода в pdf ?
Ну то есть например не так точно все переводить а получить изображения страниц например

Comment: если у вашего процессора есть несколько **полноценных** ядер, то запуск обработки нескольких файлов одновременно, по идее, должно сократить общее время пакетной обработки. если не знаете, как запускать процессы одновременно — задайте по этому поводу отдельный вопрос. а лучше поищите — сдаётся мне, уж эту-то тему обсуждали здесь множество раз.

Comment: если вопрос о производительности, то чтобы посетителей из гугла (основная аудитория SO) не вводить в заблуждение, стоит  явно отобразить это в заголовке. Без реального рабочего кода, представительных входных данных, конкретных версий ПО производительность не слишком продуктивно обсуждать. Приведите результаты измерений,  укажите что является достаточно быстрым вашем случае.